# Lazy loading of an association

Tags: ember.js, lazy-loading, ember-data

I have a Project Model, and each one hasMany tasks and a simple template :

```
<ul>
{{#each task in tasks}}
  <li>{{task.name}</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

It works fine and I can display the task list for each project by accessing /project/:id

I would like to display in my header a dropdown with the list of all projects, but I dont want to load all the tasks attached to each project, as this would be a lot of objects.
Currently my projects.json does not include the "tasks" attribute, but the project/:id.json does.

What is the best way to achieve this ?

Should I use async: true in my hasMany association, and return the ids of the tasks in my projects.json, or is is a way to avoid this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a recommended solution out there at this point.

You can read up on this [discussion of "partial" loading with ember](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/loading-partial-models-then-filling-them-with-ember-data/819) which has some good related SO issues.

One low tech way to achieve it that I am considering is to create a light object for the listing and link to the detail object via an action that finds the detailed object of the same ID.